# Monitoring AWS instance with Check_mk

Tags: amazon-web-services, check-mk

I installed OMD V1.20 (CentOS 7.x) with the help of [this tutorial](http://blog.unicsolution.com/2014/02/how-to-setup-omd-in-1-hour.html). I was able to successfully add the server itself as host and it showed some 18 processes and is running fine.

After that, I proceeded with installation of `check_mk_agent` in an AWS instance (Ubuntu 4.8.2). I am able to successfully test it using `telnet ip-of-aws-instance 6556` from the OMD host and I added it as the host.

I am only seeing PING service from this AWS host. Is there anything I am missing? How should I configure OMD/Check_mk to show all processes running in that machine?

Ping service seen in Check_MK:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you edit the agent type of the host to "Check_MK".  If it says "No Agent" this is why you only see ping.  After you check this make sure to re-inventory the host.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

By default, the host type is - Check_MK agent(server). I tried changing it to Dual: Check_MK + SNMP and did a re-inventory. 

Still only seeing PING service.

Edit: Sorry - forgot to activate the refreshed inventory with Activate changes. I see many services now. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to WATO configuration (OMD) & click on  Host, add "New host".

In hostname type your hostname and in IP type your IP address.

Then click on Save & go to service & click on "Atomatic refresh" button.

Then click on "Activate Change" button.

Before that you must add a `logwatch.cfg` file in `/etc/check_mk/logwatch.cfg`.

Finally start the `xinetd` service on the client side.